# Single word for harsh comment without emotion

Tags: meaning

A single word to describe something said that is harsh but the person does not show any emotion and you are not sure if they meant it or not.  You are left to feel unsure and confused.

Answer (score 1):

Try [brusque](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23986?rskey=7V7Pog&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (Somewhat rough or rude in manner; blunt, ‘offhand’) or [blunt](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20663?rskey=SLtMJV&result=2#eid) (Abrupt of speech or manner; plain-spoken; curt; without delicacy; unceremonious).
Both are usually used to describe people or manners of speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "phlegmatic", "apathetic", or even "pococurante" if you're feeling a little pretentious.

> **Phlegmatic**: unemotional and stolidly calm disposition.
>
> **Apathetic**: showing or feeling no interest, enthusiasm, or concern.
>
> **Pococurante**: indifferent or unconcerned.

Of course, these are all adjectives (except pococurante which can be a noun as well), rather than a replacement for "comment" itself.

Answer (score 0):

A possible term for the remark is ***uncouched***, that is the remark was not "worded in a certain manner."  It could have been *couched* diplomatically, or *couched* abrasively, but you're left wondering because it was altogether *uncouched*.

> [**couched**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/couched) -
>   To word in a certain manner; phrase: *couched their protests in diplomatic language.*